# Looping forever?

Tags: c

Hey, while trying to iterate with "next" as a pointer in my structure, it loops forever for no reason, even if i try to make a fake pointer to the structure (not with calling a function to set it up)

my code:

```
void
command_login(conn,msg)
  void *conn;
  const char *msg;
{
  const char *u,*p;
  char *home;
  ConnectionQueue* q;
  DBResult *result;
  DBResult *tmp;
  bool got_pass,got_user,admin;
  if (!conn)
    return;

  /* initalize */
  q = (ConnectionQueue *)conn;
  got_pass = false; got_user = false; admin = false;
  result = NULL;
  tmp = NULL;
  if (msg == NULL || *msg == '\0'){
    send_socket(q->conn,"LOGIN: Invalid user and password\n");
    return;
  }

  (void)strtok((char *)msg," ");
  u = strtok((char *)NULL, " ");
  p = strtok((char *)NULL, " ");
  if (!u || !p){
    send_socket(q->conn,"LOGIN: Invalid user or password\n");
    return;
  }

  printf("command_login(): u = %s, p = %s\n",u,p);
  tmp = store_query("SELECT * FROM `users`");
  if (!tmp){
    /* should never happen */
    send_socket(q->conn,"LOGIN: Failed to fetch results\n");
    return;
   }

   printf("command_login(): Checking user and password...\n");
   result = tmp;
  while (result != NULL){
     if (!got_user){
       if (strcmp(result->field_name,"user") == 0 && strcmp(result->field_value,u) == 0)
         got_user = true;
     }else if (!got_pass){
       if (strcmp(result->field_name,"pass") == 0){
          if (strcmp(result->field_value,transform_password(p)) == 0)
            got_pass = true;
       }
     }else if (!admin){
       if (strcmp(result->field_name,"admin") == 0){
         admin = boolean_string(result->field_value);
       }
     }else{
       break;
     }
     result = result->next;
  }

  free_result(result);
  printf("command_login(): Checking got user and got password\n");
  if (!got_user || !got_pass){
    send_socket(q->conn,"LOGIN: Invalid user or password\n");
    return;
  }

  printf("command_login(): Login successfully\n");
  send_socket(q->conn,"LOGIN: Success\n");
  q->conn->state &= ~S_NEED_LOGIN;
  q->admin = admin;
#ifndef _WIN32
  home = getenv("HOME");
#else
  home = getenv("HOMEPATH");
#endif
  if (!home)
    return;

  if (!chdir(home)){
    send_socket(q->conn,"LOGIN: Failed to change to user home directory %s: %s\n",home,strerror(errno));
    close_connection(q->conn);
    return;
   }
   send_socket(q->conn,"CWD: %s\n",home);
}
```

it loops forever here:

```
  while (result != NULL){
     if (!got_user){
       if (strcmp(result->field_name,"user") == 0 && strcmp(result->field_value,u) == 0)
         got_user = true;
     }else if (!got_pass){
       if (strcmp(result->field_name,"pass") == 0){
          if (strcmp(result->field_value,transform_password(p)) == 0)
            got_pass = true;
       }
     }else if (!admin){
       if (strcmp(result->field_name,"admin") == 0){
         admin = boolean_string(result->field_value);
       }
     }else{
       break;
     }
     result = result->next;
  }
```

any ideas? thanks

Comment: What does `addto_dbresult` do?

Comment: @Alex : i have added it to main post too :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new `DBResult` structure, do you set the `next` pointer to `NULL`? If you create the structure with `malloc`, your test for `result` would never end.

It's really difficult to know more without knowing the definition of `DBResult` and the definition of `store_query`. What does `store_query` return?

You say you are making a list. In `store_query` you don't actually set `next` of `ret` to `tmp`. I assume that is what you want to do. Look carefully at your list construction because it is not correct.

It might help to draw a picture of your `DBResult` as it gets constructed.

Comment: but when i output "result->field_value" and "result->field_name" it outputs them right but outputs them forever and same values... anyway added DBResult structure & store_query to main post

Comment: Looking at store_query, I really don't see how your linked list is getting stitched together. Are you making a linked list? Can you describe what the return data structure is supposed to look like?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so what you're doing is

```
ret->next = tmp;
ret = tmp;
ret->next = tmp; // = ret
```

So you're making a circular linked list with one element.  What you need to do is allocate a new element each time you add one.  Then remember to free them all at the end.

*edit*

The pattern should look like this

```
DBResult* head = NULL;
DBResult* row = NULL;

while(have_rows()) {
    row = malloc(sizeof(DBResult));
    // load row into row

    row->next = head;
    head = row;
}

return head;

// later when you're all done
while(head) {
    DBResult* element = head;
    head = head->next;
    free(element);
}
```

Comment: I have tried making "tmp" an array in "store_query" but it doesnt work

Comment: That won't work.  An array like `DBResult tmp[1]` is allocated on the stack and will be destroyed when `store_query` returns.  I meant that you actually have to have one call to `malloc` for each element that you add to the list.

Comment: I added some code to try to clarify what I mean by allocating a new element each time you add one.

Comment: any more ideas? i really need this :S